# Numpy error (module 'numpy.__config__' has no attribute 'blas_opt_info')

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I use Python 3.10.2 in the latest version of Pycharm on mac.
I made a few changes to my Pycharm setting to make installed libraries available to all projects. It seems that I did a mistake somewhere because now I am facing an issue. I get the error shown below. I have this issue for the latest version of numpy (numpy 1.22.2). But if I switch to numpy 1.21.3 I do not face this problem anymore. I prefer to use the latest version of numpy. So, I would be very grateful if you could help me.

So far to solve the problem: I uninstalled Numpy, and reinstalled it again.
I did the same for Pycharm and Python.
I checked to not have any files named numpy.py.
I do not know what else can I do to fix this problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "/Users/S/PycharmProjects/M-to-O/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from qutip import *
  
File "/Users/S/M-to-O/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qutip/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    (_blas_info() == "OPENBLAS" and platform.system() == 'Darwin')
  
File "/Users/S/M-to-O/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qutip/utilities.py", line 430, in _blas_info
    blas_info = config.blas_opt_info

AttributeError: module 'numpy.__config__' has no attribute 'blas_opt_info'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [module 'numpy.distutils.__config__' has no attribute 'blas_opt_info'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70839312/module-numpy-distutils-config-has-no-attribute-blas-opt-info).

`blas_opt_info` is located in `numpy.distutils.system_info.blas_opt_info`.

See also: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/21079

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.