# Python setup.py can't setup C extension

Tags: python, c, numpy, setup.py, blas

I'm trying to setup this github repository I found online: https://github.com/agijsberts/ssgpr

When I run "python3 setup.py install --user," I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dhruft/Projects/wildfireSwarming/DeepLearning/ssgpr/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    blas_info = numpy.__config__.blas_opt_info
AttributeError: module 'numpy.__config__' has no attribute 'blas_opt_info'
```

The full setup.py code is on the github repository I linked.

I have tried everything in this stack overflow post: [module 'numpy.distutils.__config__' has no attribute 'blas_opt_info'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70839312/module-numpy-distutils-config-has-no-attribute-blas-opt-info)

My pip and numpy are up-to-date, numpy.disutils doesn't work, and the monkey-patch doesn't do anything. Does anyone have any advice?